# Prove that $\sum_{r=1}^{3k} r \tan(60r)^{\text{o}}=-k\sqrt{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Prove that $$\sum_{r=1}^{3k} r \tan(60r)^{\text{o}}=-k\sqrt{3}$$

I did this by re-writing the sum as

$$\sum_{r=1}^{3k} r \tan(60r)^{\text{o}}=-k\sqrt{3} = \sum_{r=1}^{k} \left((3r-2)\tan(60(3r-2))^{\text{o}} + (3r-1)\tan(120(3r-1))^{\text{o}} + 3r\tan(180(3r))^{\text{o}} \right)$$

Then note that the last term is $0$ for all $r$

Next, for any $r$, $\tan(60(3r-2))^{\text{o}} = - \tan(120(3r-1))^{\text{o}}$.
Therefore,

$$\sum_{r=1}^{3k} r \tan(60r)^{\text{o}} = \sum_{r=1}^{k} \left((3r-2)\tan(60)^{\text{o}} - (3r-1)\tan(60)^{\text{o}} \right)$$

$$= \sum_{r=1}^{k} -\tan(60)^{\text{o}}$$

$$= -k\sqrt{3}$$

Two things with this:

- Is everything fully correct with what I have done?
- This was for two marks on an exam, is there an easier way??

Comment: Induction seems to work here, you would only need to worry about the last three terms of the sum up to $3(k+1)$, which is actually not too different from what you did when considering the three terms in your rewriting of the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything that you did was correct.

The easier approach is by induction, with the $k = 1$ case proved by manual inspection.

Inductively assume that 
$\displaystyle \sum_{r=1}^{3K} r\tan(r \times 60)^\circ = -K\sqrt{3}.$

To show that the assertion then applies when taking the summation from $r=1$ to $r = (3[K+1])$ is it sufficient to verify that

$\displaystyle \sum_{r = 3K+1}^{3K+3} r\tan(r \times 60)^\circ = -\sqrt{3}.$

Following much the same analysis as you did, the term by term summation of the above three terms is

$\displaystyle (K+1)\sqrt{3} + (K+2)(-1)\sqrt{3} + 0 = -\sqrt{3}.$